# Getting Batchable size is too big error

Tags: apex, batch

Here my heap size is exceeded. Heap size is 20182515 enforced is 6000000

global class CloneRAEDBatch  implements Database.Batchable{

```
Public List<Nike_Account_Team_Assignment_Rule_Stage__c> raedList;
public String strQuery;   

global CloneRAEDBatch(List<Nike_Account_Team_Assignment_Rule_Stage__c> raedList1){
 System.debug('Heap Size: ' + Limits.getHeapSize() + '/' + Limits.getLimitHeapSize());
    this.raedList=raedList1;

}

global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    return raedList;

}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Nike_Account_Team_Assignment_Rule_Stage__c> RAEDStageList) {

    if(RAEDStageList.size()>0){
           upsert RAEDStageList Dupecheck__c;

    }

     RepAssignmentExtDefTriggerHandler.createRAD(RAEDStageList,  BC.getJobId());
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a very strange use of a Batchable. Normally a batchable would return a query locator from the start method by embedding some SOQL in that start method for return. Here you already have a list of objects that, I assume, have been queried from outside the batchable code since they are passed into the constructor.

The typical flow with a batchable is that some code constructs an instance, passing in data as required, then calls Database.executeBatch or System.scheduleBatch with that instance. Note, however, that the instance provided is simply used as a "template"; these two methods basically serialize the state of that instance into the database. When the system is ready to process the batch it deserializes the state to reconstruct an instance of your batchable implementation then calls start.

Thus you should be aware that the SObject list is being serialized to the database and during this processing there will be a lot of extra memory used.

Now, I note that you commented saying you had added "the query with required fields". However, are you doing this now in your start method or are you still trying to pre-populate an SObject list? If the latter, this is the wrong approach. The point with the batch is that the system DOES NOT load all the SObjects that require processing into memory in one go, but rather it iterates, in "scope size" chunks, pulling in instances to be processed in "execute" only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things you can do to avoid such an issue:

- Make sure that you query fields, ONLY if you want to read them, for writing you don't need to extra query them
- Try to make the scope size smaller, when starting the batch. scope size is between 1-2000

---

Another thing I notice: this query is not needed, if the list is empty, the execute methode won't be exevuted.

```
if(RAEDStageList.size()>0)
```

Comment: i tried by adding the query with required fileds ..still i am getting the error..here in constructor itself i am getting the issue..And i am giving batch size as 2000 only..The list contains 22880 records.